# WordPress Header Issues

Tags: wordpress

Hey guys I'm fairly new to WordPress and get an error of:

> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home2/zoeflav/public_html/index.php:2) in /home2/zoeflav/public_html/blog/wp-content/plugins/wp-super-cache/wp-cache-phase2.php on line 62

On my index.php file I get this:

```
"; echo "; the_post_thumbnail(); echo "; the_title(); echo "; echo "; echo"; endwhile; ?>
```

This is my code from lines 59-71

```
If($wp_cache_gzip_encoding)
        header('Vary: Accept-Encoding, Cookie');
    else
        header('Vary: Cookie');
    ob_start( 'wp_cache_ob_callback' ); 
    if ( isset( $GLOBALS[ 'wp_super_cache_debug' ] ) && $GLOBALS[ 'wp_super_cache_debug' ] ) wp_cache_debug( 'Created output buffer', 4 );

    // restore old supercache file temporarily
    if( $super_cache_enabled && $cache_rebuild_files ) {
        $user_info = wp_cache_get_cookies_values();
        $do_cache = apply_filters( 'do_createsupercache', $user_info );
        if( $user_info == '' || $do_cache === true )
            wpcache_do_rebuild( get_current_url_supercache_dir() );
```

How can I get rid of this warning message, sorry if I sound like a noob, but like I said I'm fairly new to this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix "Headers already sent" error in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028957/how-to-fix-headers-already-sent-error-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

try to disable cache plugin and restore your index.php file to [original wordpress
index.php file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/WordPress/WordPress/master/index.php)